# Ruby best way to sum diagonal values of a matrix

Tags: ruby, matrix

Giving a certain position of an egg in a matrix. I need to sum all the eggs of the target row, column and diagonals.

- Egg -> 1
- Empty -> 0

I've done a method called egg_performance where I pass as parameters the position of egg. In this method I calculate the rows, columns and all the diagonals. I have no problem with the rows and columns. When I sum the diagonals I used this pice of code (This is only for the second quadrant taking as point of reference the curent egg).

```
# Second quadrant of the diagonals of the egg
x = egg_x - 1
y = egg_y - 1
while x >= 0 && x < egg_x || y >= 0 && y < egg_y
  performance += 1 if @carton[y][x] == 1
  x -= 1
  y -= 1
end
```

When I execute this pice of code an error shows up. I think it's an out of bounds error but i can't find it.

```
./carton.rb:73:in `egg_performance': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from ./carton.rb:20:in `generate_random'
    from main.rb:5
```

I don't like the way I've done that. Is there a better ruby way to do it?

[carton.rb](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=wnGJnxn9)
[main.rb](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=iS3ZMert)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The error is because either `@carton` or `@carton[y]` is `nil`, which is not defined according to the code you've put into your question. Paste your relevant code here (into your question), not on a third-party page.

Comment: What do you mean by "all diagonals"? Can you please illustrate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have array of matrix columns, you can do:

```
require 'matrix'
Matrix.columns(array_of_columns).trace
```